# How can I check if a list matches with a list of types?

Tags: python

Currently I have the following list of strings:

```
types = ['int', 'int']
```

And a list of values:

```
values = [1, 'b']
```

**The problem I have:**

They will always both be the same length, so how can I iterate through both of them so if the types don't match in the same element on both lists, it would raise an AssertionError with the index that failed the match?

**For example:**

In the above example, the second element of `values` is `b` which is `str`. However, in the list of `types`, the second element is an `"int"` so this would essentially raise an AssertionError.

---

**My attempt at it:**

```
def ok(types, values):
    for index, item in enumerate(values):
        for type_name in types:
            if type(item) != eval(type_name):
                raise AssertionError("Index: {} has failed".format(index))



types = ['int', 'int']
values = [1, 'b']

ok(types, values)
```

**Current Output:** AssertionError: Index 0 has failed

I see that it is failing because it is iterating through the second for loop multiple times.

---

**Expected Output:** AssertionError: Index 1 has failed

Comment: The right way to do it depends on why you’re doing it, so… what necessitated this?

Comment: I get your expected output; what's the question?

Comment: It's simply for an assignment I have. I have a list of strings, disguised as types, which can be called with eval().

Comment: So, if you actually *used the types* instead of strings, you could do: `values = [1, 'b']; types = [int, int]`; then  `for i, (v, t) in enumerate(zip(values, types)): if not isinstance(v, t): AssertionError("Index: {} has failed".format(i))`

Comment: What was the result of your attempt?

Comment: I'm gonna go ahead and say this is probably a dupe of [How to iterate through two lists in parallel?](//stackoverflow.com/q/1663807). Because that's really the only bug in the OP's code.

Comment: Also your code doesn't do what you think it does. It checks if the current element has *any* type of `types`

Comment: This should work for you: https://gist.github.com/jszakmeister/fea44d547fe124c0db17284413ce4720

Comment: [Alternative version](https://pastebin.com/jADAnYDu), which is maybe a bit easier to read